# enable obfuscation for GWT css classes?

Tags: java, css, gwt, obfuscation

I have set the style config param in gwt maven plugin configuration to OBFUSCATED (using maven). However, only my own resource bundle's styles get obfuscated while GWT's standard theme don't.

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use the maven plugin for GWT, but I guess you are confusing the compiler (javascript) output style (`OBFUSCATED`|`PRETTY`|`DETAILED`), with the `CSS` style (which does not exist as option).

Style obfuscation is a `CssResource`'s feature, i.e., when you use a `CssResource` of a `ClientBundle`, all selectors gets obfuscated by default. Standard `GWT` themes are not obfuscated, and all selectors are actually hardcoded into almost any widgets (well, old ones) via calls to `setStyleName("gwt-WidgetName")`.

Comment: Actually, there is a module parameter for css obfuscation: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/resources/Resources.gwt.xml?r=10282 -- however, it does not obfuscate inherited resources.